# Can anyone explain what am i doing wrong

Tags: python, list

Question:-Write a Python function transpose(m) that takes as input a two dimensional matrix m and returns the transpose of m. The argument m should remain undisturbed by the function.

```
def transpose(l):
m=l[:]
lst=[[] for x in range(len(m[0)]
for i in range(0,len(m)):
    for j in range(0,len(m[i])):
        lst[j].append(m[i][j])
return lst
l=[[1,2,3,4,5],[4,5,6,7,8,9]]
```

ERROR
lst[j].append(m[i][j])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: If `len(m[i])` is greater than `len(m)`, then `lst[j]` is an `IndexError`. Your code is only guaranteed to work for square matrices.

Comment: There's a typo here for a start: `range(len(m[0)]`

Comment: your input is a list of lists, not a 2 dimensional matrix.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki For the purposes of this question, it's fine to assume the OP means the nested list *represents* a 2-dimensinal matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Your List `l` has two lists with 5 and 6 elements.

So, the range of `j` in `range(len(m[1]))` is 0 - 5 (6 numbers), which results in index out of range for `lst` (which only have 5 elements).

```py
def transpose(l):
    lst=[[] for x in range(len(l[0]))]
    for i in range(len(l)):
        for j in range(len(l[i])):
            lst[j].append(l[i][j])
    return lst
l = [[1,2,3,4,5],[4,5,6,7,8]]
```

But I would add a checking part at the beginning of the function

```py
def transpose(l):
    iterator = iter(l)
    lists_len = len(next(iterator))
    if not all(len(a) == lists_len for a in iterator):
        # Do something here

    lst=[[] for x in range(len(l[0]))]
    for i in range(len(l)):
        for j in range(len(l[i])):
            lst[j].append(l[i][j])
    return lst
```